# Unexpected token '

Tags: json, charts

```
$.parseJSON("[['dt', 'Bin Marking1', 'Bin Materials1', 'Bin Marking2', 'Bin Materials2', ' Engine Loading'], ['20-01-2015 03:56:51', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]");
```

When run on application as well console gives error:

> Unexpected token `'`.

This is needed for Google chart, to convert string into a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the JSON specification (http://www.json.org/), all string values have to be specified using double quotations: `"` and not single quotations: `'`. The code you have shown is therefore syntactically incorrect. The proper way would be to interchange the double and single quotations like this:

```
$.parseJSON('[["dt", "BinMarking1", "BinMaterials1", "BinMarking2", "BinMaterials2", "EngineLoading"], ["20-01-201503: 56: 51", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]');
```